# Network data in Truffle when deploying a smart contract to Aurora

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, nearprotocol

I had a question about deploying a contract to Aurora (https://aurora.dev/).
Aside from changing the network data in the truffle file. Is there any other adjustments that need to be made?
And what Solidity compiler versions are compatible?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the network data in the truffle file should be enough. And regarding solidity versioning - anything in the EVM byte code should work.